# Is the Reactive framework available for .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

IObservable and IObserver would be quite handy right now for something I'm working on.

Is there a similar set of interfaces and classes available for .NET 3.5?

Or must I wait for .NET 4.0 before I can use them?

Comment: New answer: Yes, as of today:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post -- [Rebasing System.Reactive to the .NET CLR](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/07/30/rebasing-system-reactive-to-the-net-clr) -- explains how you can get the .dll from Silverlight Toolkit to work with .NET 3.5. Don't miss the update at the end (and the comments).

Answer (score 1):

I did the re basing and created a small WPF drawing app. Here is the source code

[LINQ to Events – More on .NET Reactive Extensions (Rx) and a .NET 3.5 WPF Demo](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/11/linq-to-events-more-on-net-reactive.html)